# Apply gradient to label in UICollectionViewCell

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout, snapkit

I am trying to apply the gradient to a UILabel in one of the cells in my UICollectionView.

Following some responses online I added the extension to UIImage:

```
extension UIImage {
    static func gradientImageWithBounds(bounds: CGRect, colors: [CGColor]) -> UIImage {
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame = bounds
        gradientLayer.colors = colors
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(gradientLayer.bounds.size)
        if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
            gradientLayer.render(in: context )
            let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            return image!

        }
        return UIImage()
    }
}
```

and when I apply it to a normal label it works like a charm:

```
let gradientImage = UIImage.gradientImageWithBounds(bounds: someLabel.bounds, colors: [UIColor.black.cgColor, UIColor.white.cgColor])
someLabel.textColor = UIColor.init(patternImage: gradientImage)
```

The problem is, the label I want to apply the gradient to is a part of a UICollectionViewCell and when I try to do it:

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        addSubview(nameLabel)
        nameLabel.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.top.bottom.trailing.equalToSuperview()
            make.leading.equalToSuperview().inset(10)
        }

        let gradientImage = UIImage.gradientImageWithBounds(bounds: nameLabel.bounds, colors: [UIColor.black.cgColor, UIColor.white.cgColor])
        nameLabel.textColor = UIColor.init(patternImage: gradientImage)
    }
```

it doesn't work. 
When I stopped execution right before creating the gradientImage unfortunately nameLabel.bounds is equal 0:

```
(lldb) po nameLabel.bounds
▿ (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
  ▿ origin : (0.0, 0.0)
    - x : 0.0
    - y : 0.0
  ▿ size : (0.0, 0.0)
    - width : 0.0
    - height : 0.0
```

Is there a way to get the bounds for the label within the UICollectionViewCell definition? Does it depend on how I define the UICollectionView? What am I missing?

Alternatively, do you know any other way to have a label inside UICollectionViewCell with a gradient?

I tried setting the size in:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
return CGSize(width: 100, height: 60)
}
```

I tried changing the definition of layout from automatic to

```
layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 60)
```

Nothing seems to help.

Comment: That's probably because during initialization, the frame is not defined yet. What you can do is apply it when you set the text for the label inside the cellForItem function.

Comment: @rs7 I actually started from there but in the cellForItemAt function the nameLabel.bounds were still 0. However,  I tried that `again and saw that cell.bounds are not 0 and I am able to work with that so thank you! 
I wonder why the frame for the label itself was not defined yet though...

Comment: You are welcome. After looking at your code again, I noticed that you are laying out your views inside a closure. Have you tried moving the relevant 2 lines of code inside the closure? That might solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be that you are laying out your views inside a closure asynchronously. In other words, before your views are laid out, the following statement is getting executed and that would explain why the bounds are not set yet.

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        addSubview(nameLabel)
        nameLabel.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.top.bottom.trailing.equalToSuperview()
            make.leading.equalToSuperview().inset(10)
            let gradientImage = UIImage.gradientImageWithBounds(bounds: nameLabel.bounds, colors: [UIColor.black.cgColor, UIColor.white.cgColor])
            self.nameLabel.textColor = UIColor.init(patternImage: gradientImage)

        }
    }
```